# Why do I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING?

Tags: php

I can't seem to figure out the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/25/11427125/html/connect.php on line 16

Here's the whole code:

```
<?php

 echo "Under Construction. Please try again soon!";
//-------MYSQL INFO LOGIN--------
$host = '******';
$user = 'RootSpread';
$pass = '******';
$db   =  'accounts';

$ms = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass);
if ( !$ms )
{
  echo "Error connecting to database.\n";
}

mysql_query (' INSERT INTO account ('firstname', 'initial', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'dob', 'number', 'sex')
VALUES ('','','')';

mysql_close($ms);

?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a quote mismatch error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

This line caused the error:

```
mysql_query (' INSERT INTO account ('firstname', 'initial', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'dob', 'number', 'sex')
VALUES ('','','')';
```

Change it to:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO account ('firstname', 'initial', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'dob', 'number', 'sex') VALUES ('','','')");
```

Comment: man, everyone is so fast!

Comment: Three minutes after the OP's question? Nahh,.. Not fast enough

Comment: Not that syntax error question should be answered anyway. But the SQL syntax is still off...

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query (' INSERT INTO account ('firstname', 'initial', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'dob', 'number', 'sex')
VALUES ('kevin','','miqui')';
```

needs to be

```
mysql_query (" INSERT INTO account ('firstname', 'initial', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'dob', 'number', 'sex') VALUES ('kevin','','miqui')");
```

so that the entire query is a string.

you need to use `"` to denote your string rather than `'` to ensure that PHP knows what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the single quotes in the query. The unescapted single quote in front of firstname causes the error, because PHP thinks the query is finished. But instead of a semicolon there is a string after that! If your Editor has syntax highlighting, you should see that firstname has not the same color like the query before.